# mcpi-e. error when getting coordinates. mc.player.getPos()

Tags: python, minecraft

Code:

```
from mcpi_e.minecraft import Minecraft

mc = Minecraft.create('127.0.0.1', 4711)
pos = mc.player.getPos()
```

When trying to get coordinates.
mc.player.getPos()

an error pops up

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\merka\Desktop\pyt minecraft\buy.py", line 23, in <module>
    pos = mc.player.getPos()
  File "C:\Users\merka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mcpi_e\minecraft.py", line 230, in getPos
    return CmdPositioner.getPos(self, self.playerId)
  File "C:\Users\merka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mcpi_e\minecraft.py", line 50, in getPos
    s = self.conn.sendReceive(self.pkg + b".getPos", id)
  File "C:\Users\merka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mcpi_e\connection.py", line 103, in sendReceive
    return self.receive()
  File "C:\Users\merka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mcpi_e\connection.py", line 97, in receive
    raise RequestError("%s failed"%self.lastSent.strip())
mcpi_e.connection.RequestError: b'entity.getPos()' failed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
mc = Minecraft.create('127.0.0.1', 4711, "merka")
```

I should have added a nickname